# How to access files in a Powershell Binary Module FileList Property

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a file bundled with a powershell binary module.  It has a line in the manifest which details the attached file.

```
# List of all files packaged with this module
FileList = @(".\assets\MoonPhase.sqlite")
```

[This FileList preoperty seems to be pretty useless, just as a note?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest)

> List of all files packaged with this module. As with ModuleList, FileList is to assist you as an inventory list, and is not otherwise processed.

How can I then access this file relative the the module root from a cmdlet?

The following seems to be evaluated only when called when the cmndlet is called from a script.  Therefore it is not really part of the module but the invocation as the name would suggest.

```
string path = this.MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot + "\\assets\\MoonPhase.sqlite";
string path = this.MyInvocation.PSCommandPath + "\\assets\\MoonPhase.sqlite";
```

The following seems a poor choice

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Me\Path\Project\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\assets\MoonPhase.sqlite";
```

Comment: Is there any reason the file has to be included as part of the module and not created on first run in a shared system folder such as ProgramData? If you need to include it could you provide some detail as to why it would need to be accessed outside of a cmdlet?

Comment: @persistent13.  The SQLite contains data that the module/cmdlet use to compute an answer.  It is for read only purposes not for completion during use of the module.  I guess I could copy it to a know location or otherwise store the location of the module in a varialbe using a script that runs at import-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileList Property is available inside the MyInvocation object and the files listed in the manifest have absolute paths.

```
string path = MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.FileList
#"C:\\Users\\Me\\Path\\Project\\bin\\Debug\\assets\\MoonPhase.sqlite"
```

It's an IEnumerable so need to get a string out of it with linq, a loop or by casting.

```
string path = MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.FileList.First();
```

The following is also useful for forming relative paths

```
string path = MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.ModuleBase
#"C:\\Users\\Me\\Path\\Project\\bin\\Debug"

string path = MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module.ModuleBase + "\\OtherFile.txt"
#"C:\\Users\\Me\\Path\\Project\\bin\\Debug\\OtherFile.txt"
```